# Is there a way to add your own voice to Speak[]?

Tags: sound

Is it possible and how can I create my own voice and apply it to the function `Speak`?

Answer (score 3):

From the help files, it sounds like Mathematica uses the system's text-to-speech processor.  Windows 10 has three built-in voices, David, Zira, and Mark. You can switch between them, plus more can be loaded for other languages.  It looks like Microsoft has a service for creating custom voices:

https://speech.microsoft.com/custom

Comment: What about using NetTrain?